# How exactly to pass values in function arguments to be unpacked as ```{} = a``` later in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working with a node.js code base and the way a function is defined is something as shown below

```
x = async (record) => {

    const {a, b, c} = record;
    // do something with a, b, c
}
```

I am not sure how to pass arguments to this function.
I've tried `x({"a", "b", "c"})` and `x("a", "b", "c")` but it doesn't seem to be working as the values in console when logging them are shown as undefined.

Comment: `{"a", "b", "c"}` ---> `{a: <someValue>, b: <someValue>, c: : <someValue>}` or if `a`, `b `, and `c` are variables with some values, then: `{ a, b, c }`

Comment: [Destructuring assignment - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code works for me, not sure what you tried:

```
const x = async (record) => {

    const {a, b, c} = record;
    // do something with a, b, c
    console.log(a, b, c)
}

x({ a: 12, b: 13, c: 14 })
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing string in object, that is not a valid syntax. You should pass `key-value` pair

```js
const x = async (record) => {
  const { a, b, c } = record;
  console.log(a, b, c);
  // do something with a, b, c
};

const a = "a",
  b = "b",
  c = "c";

x({ a: "a", b: "b", c: "c" });
```

or

```js
const x = async (record) => {
  const { a, b, c } = record;
  console.log(a, b, c)
  // do something with a, b, c
};

const a = "a",
  b = "b",
  c = "c";

x({ a, b, c });
```

Comment: I've accepted it now. I wasn't allowed to, it needs to take some specific time before an answer is accepted. Thanks again